# trouble with scope related variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Hello fellow programmers, I'm developing a simple interface application in Python that will enable easy and intuitive entry of inventory forms in an access database.

I currently have a function as follows:

```
def spawnerror(self, errormsg):
    self.running = False
    content = Button(text=errormsg)
    popup = Popup(title='ERROR!', content=content, auto_dismiss=False)
    content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
    popup.open()
```

And I have appropriate error handling done, and the application uses this function as intended. For example, if someone doesn't enter in a required field, it calls this function and spawns an error page with an error and informs the user.

My issue that I run into is that, it needs to set the class variable **running** to False, because at the end of the main function "submit" it checks for that and if self.running == False, then it needs to skip the execution of data entry in the access database.

Why is this function not setting the class variable of running to false?

Comment: Where is self.running defined/declared?

Comment: self.running is declared directly after the class declaration of MyApp(App):

Comment: Please refer to my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution - using App.get_running_app()

In the example, a class attribute, `running` is defined as BooleanProperty. In the `spawnerror()` function, it uses `App.get_running_app()` function to get an instance of App class and then access variable, `running`.

## Note

If *running*, *spawnerror()* function and *submit()* function are in different classes then work out the relation of the classes and pass a direct reference between them.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    instance = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.instance = App.get_running_app()
        self.spawnerror('Testing')

    def spawnerror(self, errormsg):
        self.instance.running = False
        content = Button(text=errormsg)
        popup = Popup(title='ERROR!', content=content, auto_dismiss=False)
        content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()


class TestApp(App):
    running = BooleanProperty(True)

    def build(self):
        print("\nbuild:")
        self.display_attributes()
        return RootWidget()

    def on_stop(self):
        print("\non_stop:")
        self.display_attributes()

    def display_attributes(self):
        print("\tApp.running =", self.running)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Thank you! You helped me learn how to reference class specific variables. I was successfully able to incorporate your example into my working solution. +1!